# ERROR - Couldn't find User with 'id'=2 - unable to solve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

im using rails to make a basic chair selling website. At the moment someone can post a new chair and people can look at each individual show page. However im having issues with the show page when trying to display the email of who posted the chair.
If i click on the first chair, it works fine, however if i click on the other it says 'Couldn't find User with 'id'=2'. I have made all the chairs under 1 user.
thanks. let me know if you need anymore info.

```html
class ChairsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @chairs = Chair.all
  end

  def show
    @chair = Chair.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @chair = Chair.new
    @user = current_user
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @chair = Chair.new(chair_params)
    @chair.user = @user
    if @chair.save
      redirect_to chairs_path
    end

  end


  private

  def chair_params
    params.require(:chair).permit(:name, :description)
  end
end
```

```html
<h1><%= @chair.name %></h1>

posted by <%= @user.email %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you try to load the user by the same `params[:id]` as the chair your `show` method.  Change your `show` method to:

```
def show
  @chair = Chair.find(params[:id])
  @user = @chair.user
end
```

Comment: You're fast! Just about to say the same thing.

Comment: ah perfect. thanks very much. Could you please explain how this works? im relatively new to rails.

Comment: Your `Chair` model has probably a `belongs_to :user` line. In your `create` method you assign the `current_user` to that `user` association. In the `show` method you read that user again. I suggest to read about [Associations in the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).